# @SessionAtribute call issue in @RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-security

I use Spring Security for auth. and I save in @SessionAttribut this auth becouse of I want to access user object.

### ADVICE METHOD

```
@ControllerAdvice(basePackages= {"com.sencerseven.blog.admin","com.sencerseven.blog.controller"})
@SessionAttributes("User")
public class SessionScope {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @ModelAttribute("User")
    public User session() {
        Authentication authentication = 
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

            if(authentication != null) {
                User user = userService.getByEmail(authentication.getName());
                if(user != null) {
                    return user;    
                }

            }
            return null;
    }
}
```

---

### Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/post")
public class PostController {


@RequestMapping(value= {"/{post}"})
public ModelAndView postPage(@SessionAttribute("User")User tempUser,@PathVariable("post")String tempPostName ) throws NotFoundException  {
 ...
 .....
}


@PostMapping("addcomment")
@ResponseBody
public String saveComment(@SessionAttribute("User")User tempUser,@RequestParam("post_id")int id,@RequestParam("comment")String tempComment) {
 ....
 .....
}


}
```

@SessionAttribute("User") is return null in PostPage method.And page throws exception

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException at com.sencerseven.blog.controller.PostController.postPage(PostController.jav   a:54) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
```

.But SaveComment method is right working.@SessionAttribute("User") in SaveComment access user object it is not null return.

Why ? How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Since session() return null when authenticate failed, maybe it's here. Try to return a default user or print log to verify this.

Comment: Work with the framework not around it. Spring Security allows you to simply inject the `Authentication` object or your own user you don' t need to add it to the session yourself. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-authentication-principal and just use that instead of working around it.

Comment: Also, as I mentioned in one of your other (now deleted?) questions, is that `@SessionAttributes` and `@SessionAttribute` are different things and aren't supposed to be used like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Security already supports this out-of-the-box (as documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-authentication-principal)). You are making things complex by trying to shoehorn in your own implementation. Instead of using `@SessionAttribute` use the `@AuthenticationPrincipal` annotation to let Spring Security find and inject the user.

So basically remove your `SessionScope` controller advice and replace `@SessionAttribute` with `@AuthenticationPrincipal` on your controller.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/post")
public class PostController {


    @RequestMapping(value= {"/{post}"})
    public ModelAndView postPage(@AuthenticationPrincipal User tempUser, @PathVariable("post") String tempPostName ) throws NotFoundException  {
        ...
    }

    @PostMapping("addcomment")
    @ResponseBody
    public String saveComment(@AuthenticationPrincipal User tempUser, @RequestParam("post_id") int id, @RequestParam("comment") String tempComment) {
        ...
    }       
}
```

You will have to make sure that your own `User` is also the `User` used by Spring Security. If that isn't the case instead of a controller advice use a custom `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` which adds your own `User` to the `Session` just once (instead on each request).